# как отсортировать массив структур по одному полю по алфавиту С++

Tags: c++, сортировка, struct, for

```
#define ST1 1000
struct spisok_perevozki {
    unsigned nomer_perevozki;
    char data_perevozki[20];
    double ve_gruza_v_tonah;
    unsigned dlyna_puti;
    char PHIO[50];
    unsigned kod_mashini;
    unsigned kod_voditelya;
}list_spisok_perevozki[ST1];


void display() { //функция вывода полей структур
    cout << "Номер перевозки " << " Дата перевозки " << " Код водителя " << " ФИО водителя " << " Код машины " << " Вес груза в тоннах " << " Длина пути в километрах\n\n";

    for (int k = 0; k < ST1; k++) {
        if (list_spisok_perevozki[k].dlyna_puti) {
            cout.width(10); cout << list_spisok_perevozki[k].nomer_perevozki + 1;
            cout.width(15); cout << list_spisok_perevozki[k].data_perevozki;
            cout.width(12); cout << list_spisok_perevozki[k].kod_voditelya + 1;
            cout.width(20); cout << list_spisok_perevozki[k].PHIO;
            cout.width(11); cout << list_spisok_perevozki[k].kod_mashini + 1;
            cout.width(16); cout << list_spisok_perevozki[k].ve_gruza_v_tonah;
            cout.width(22); cout << list_spisok_perevozki[k].dlyna_puti;
            cout << endl;
        }

    }



void sort() {
    char temp[50];
    int tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < ST1 - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ST1 - i - 1; j++) {
            if (strcmp(list_spisok_perevozki[j].PHIO,list_spisok_perevozki[j+1].PHIO)>0 && list_spisok_perevozki[j].dlyna_puti) {

                strcpy_s(temp,list_spisok_perevozki[j].PHIO);
                strcpy_s(list_spisok_perevozki[j].PHIO,list_spisok_perevozki[j+1].PHIO);
                strcpy_s(list_spisok_perevozki[j+1].PHIO, temp);


                tmp = list_spisok_perevozki[j].nomer_perevozki;
                list_spisok_perevozki[j].nomer_perevozki = list_spisok_perevozki[j + 1].nomer_perevozki;
                list_spisok_perevozki[j + 1].nomer_perevozki = tmp;

                tmp = list_spisok_perevozki[j].nomer_perevozki;
                list_spisok_perevozki[j].nomer_perevozki = list_spisok_perevozki[j + 1].nomer_perevozki;
                list_spisok_perevozki[j + 1].nomer_perevozki = tmp;

                strcpy_s(temp, list_spisok_perevozki[j].data_perevozki);
                strcpy_s(list_spisok_perevozki[j].data_perevozki, list_spisok_perevozki[j + 1].data_perevozki);
                strcpy_s(list_spisok_perevozki[j + 1].data_perevozki, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    void display();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж C++ - воспользоваться **стандартным** алгоритмом `sort`.

```
std::sort(list_spisok_perevozki,list_spisok_perevozki+ST1,
          [](const auto& l1, const auto& l2)
          { return strcmp(l1.PHIO,l2.PHIO) < 0; });
```

P.S. У вас в самом деле их 1000 в списке, что вы всю тысячу пытаетесь сортировать?...

Comment: это для vector, а мне нужно для моего случая

Comment: так гораздо меньше 1000

Comment: Это стандартный алгоритм, отлично работает для массива :) Вы сначала попробуйте, а потом говорите... А сортируете вы `for (int i = 0; i < ST1 - 1; i++)` - `ST1`, который определен как `#define ST1 1000` - так что не знаю уж, сколько у вас там в массиве, но вы сортируете всю тысячу...